# How to call mounted or created within a Vue plugin?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to create some plugins according to this article:

https://alligator.io/vuejs/creating-custom-plugins/

I have a plugin that needs to run something when the root Vue instance mounts or is created. So far I can only see a way to inject something into all components which is not what I would want.

I simply need to do something when the main Vue instance mounts. How can I do this with a plugin?

The `install` method from the plugin does not seem to do the trick because this seems to happen before the actual `created` method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's possible to have multiple root Vue components. A "root component" is just a component created with the `new` syntax and no parent component, so you can detect this as follows:

```js
Vue.mixin({
  created() {
    if (!this.$parent) {
      // This is either the root component or a component
      // created with `new` and no parent
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: This check will now be performed for every single component. Is there really not a more efficient way to get this done?

Comment: I don't believe so, no. There is no *single* distinct "root" component that Vue is aware of to provide you with such a hook. Maybe you should invert the control so that the root component is responsible for initializing the plugin in its `created` hook.

Comment: By the way, how would you add a single watch property to the main root instance without adding it to every single instance?

Comment: You would have to manually invoke the [`$watch`](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch) method on the instance.

Comment: Fixed it with a mixin for now. Thanks for your help man, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually easy to include mixins for just a particular component!

In your component that you want to add the mixin to, just import it like you would anything else, and include an array in your component called mixins like so:

```
import myMixin from 'src/mixin/myMixin'
export default {
  mixins: [myMixin]
}
```

Then your myMixin code would look like this (don't use Vue.mixin, which is global):

```
export default {
  beforeMount () {
    console.log('Your component is about to be mounted!')
  }
}
```